# java extract method for bufferedreader and bufferedwriter

Tags: java, extract, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I have to methods. One reads from file, another writes to it. If to look at them, they differ only in local variable:

```
public method1 wtite() {
  try {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
  } catch (here come catch cases equal in two methods)
}

public method1 read() {
  try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  } catch (here come catch cases equal in two methods)
}
```

I want to extract a single method from both. And depending what the incoming object is: open file or close it. Smth like this:

```
public fileIO(??? io) {
  try{
    //read or write
  } catch//put the same code here
}
```

Is it possible to combine Writer and Reader under the same method?

Comment: No, there is no way to unify reading and writing.  But you may want to declare your methods to throw IOException instead of catching it.

Comment: I don't think it would be a good idea, and not worth it for 5 lines each. However, if you have a large common piece of code before or after the creation of the BufferedReader/Writer, you could factorize those snippet into functions, and call the functions before/after.

Comment: *Roberto Attias* can you show an example? Please...

Answer (score 0):

Excract common parts into methods:

```
void handle(...) {
    // handle exception
}

public void read(...) {
    try {
    ...
    } catch (...) {
        handle(...); // use defined method
    }
}
public void write(...) {
    try {
    ...
    } catch (...) {
        handle(...); // and here
    }
}
```